# gcc 5.3 inline assembler bug?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I've got this 32-bit code:

```
unsigned long long load(volatile unsigned long long *target) {
   unsigned long long result;

   __asm__ __volatile__
       (
       "movl %%ecx, %%edx\n\t"
       "movl %%ebx, %%eax\n\t"
       "lock cmpxchg8b %0\n\t"
       "movl %%edx, 4%1\n\t"
       "movl %%eax, %1\n\t"
       : "+m" (*target)
       : "o" (result)
       : "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx", "memory", "cc"
       );
   return result;
}
```

When it's compiled with gcc version 5.3, the tail end of the code produces this assembly code (slightly edited for clarity):

```
lock cmpxchg8b (%esi)
movl %edx, 48(%esp)
movl %eax, 8(%esp)
movl    8(%esp), %eax
movl    12(%esp), %edx
```

The result of the call to `cmpxchg8b` is in EDX:EAX. The generated code stores EDX at 48(%esp), the reloads EDX from 12(%esp), so the returned value is nonsense. Other versions of gcc get this right.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this bug? Or am I misunderstanding something fundamental about gcc's inline asm (which wouldn't surprise me)?

Comment: `4%1`? What that's even supposed to mean? Did you want `4+%1` maybe? Note that `o` constraint means _a small integer may be **added** to the address and the result is also a valid memory address._

Comment: Of course that's not very good use of inline asm, better would be to just leave the output in `edx` and `eax` and let the compiler handle it. Also gcc has atomic builtins so you probably don't even need inline asm at all.

Comment: @HubertApplebaum - gcc -S test.cpp, with gcc 5.3.

Comment: In addition to the excellent points in Jester's answer, %1 is an input.  If you are writing to it, it needs to be an output or input/output.

Comment: @Jester - thanks, changing `4%1` to `4+%1` fixed some problems in other places, although not this particular one.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd - thanks, that was a rather silly mistake. Incidentally, removing EBX and ECX from the clobber list got rid of the symptoms, although it clearly isn't the **right** answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `o` constraint means *a small integer may be **added** to the address and the result is also a valid memory address*, so the correct expression is `4+%1`. Your version may work by accident if the generated address happens to use a negative offset such as `-8(%ebp)` in which case after substitution it becomes `4-8%(ebp)`. If the offset is positive, like in the broken case `8(%esp)` it of course expands to `48(%esp)` which is wrong. `4+%1` will correctly work in both cases, since `4+-8(%esp)` is valid just as `4+8(%esp)`. This is not directly related to compiler versions.

That said, this inline asm is not very efficient, the whole business of storing `eax` and `edx` could be avoided if you just declared them as outputs and left it to the compiler to take care of it:

```
unsigned long long load(volatile unsigned long long *target) {
   unsigned long long result;

   __asm__ __volatile__
       (
       "movl %%ecx, %%edx\n\t"
       "movl %%ebx, %%eax\n\t"
       "lock cmpxchg8b %0\n\t"
       : "+m" (*target), "=&A" (result)
       :
       : "cc"
       );
   return result;
}
```

Also note that neither `ebx` nor `ecx` are modified so no point in listing them as clobbers, and of course no other memory is touched so `memory` can be removed too.

All of the above is not really necessary, since gcc has atomic builtins, so the whole thing just boils down to `__atomic_load_n(target, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)`. The compiler also knows that `lock cmpxchg8b` is slow, and can select more efficient instructions as appropriate for the targeted environment. This builtin is also more portable.

Comment: I'm not clear on how you can use ecx and ebx without initializing them. Is the assumption that the calling convention for load() is going to populate them? Will that work if it gets inlined? I'd be tempted to use inputs for them just in case. And while the "memory" clobber is not required for the cmpxchg8b to work, perhaps writing this value serves as a trigger for another thread who will begin reading values from the current thread's data structures. Most anytime I'm thinking `lock` I'm thinking "memory." All of which just highlights what you said: use atomics (__atomic_compare_exchange_n?).

Comment: We don't care about the values in `ebx` or `ecx`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested code, and for the mention of the gcc builtins.